# How to setup Xcode to run C++20?

Tags: xcode, c++20

How do I run c++ 20 code (eg , concepts) in Xcode.

The C++ language dialect is set to C++20[-std=c++20] and Standard Library is set to libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support). I checked the compiler support website https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support and Apple Clang 12.0.0 has partial support for Concepts. I am running 13.0.0.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you

I set the flags to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Setting the language dialect is all you need to do. What exact features were you looking for? It's possible that the feature is simply not implemented.

Comment: Hi @Ranoiaetep , I want use Concepts!

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the latest version of Xcode from the App Store.

Once Xcode is installed, open it and go to the “Preferences” tab.

In the “Languages & Regions” tab, select “C++20” from the dropdown menu.

In the “Build Settings” tab, set the “Compiler for C/C++” to “Clang 10.0” or higher.

Finally, in the “Build Phases” tab, add the “-std=c++20” flag to the “Other C Flags” section.

Now you are ready to write and compile C++20 programs in Xcode!

Comment: Hi Javid , thank you for the response. Under the build settings I only see a default Apple Clang Option.

Comment: In Xcode 14.3.1, setting "Other C Flags" and ignoring the other settings above worked for me.

Comment: None of those options works for me in Xcode 15 with Clang 15, I'm trying: import std; and compiler does not recognise it, too weird